# Levitton 20amp single outlet - only brass screws?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I’m doing a kitchen renovation and the electrician only left the romex cable coming out of the wall for the microwave and didn’t install an outlet (presumably because he didn’t know exactly where the cabinet would align to). I bought a surface mount box to put in the microwave cabinet and trying to hook up the outlet now. I bought a 20amp single outlet from Levitton, but there are only 2 brass screws for 2 hot wires. The romex cable has a black, white, and ground. Did I buy the wrong kind of outlet? [image]

Comment: It appears you may have purchased a 240V outlet rather than a 120V.

Comment: You brought an outlet for 240 volts, a 6-20.  You want a 5-20 for 120 volts.  Make sure what voltage the circuit is.  White can be used as the second hot in some circuits.

Comment: I do not know of any microwaves that do not use neutral(white), so there is a very good chance that circuit is 120 volt.

Comment: Show us a picture of the info plate or installation instructions for the microwave.

Comment: Thanks everyone, yes it is a 240V, I bought it before the microwave arrived in preparation and now that I’m reading the instruction manual, it says all that is needed is 120V so I will exchange.

Answer (score 4):

### That's a NEMA 6-20 for 240V

The outlet you bought is a NEMA 6-20 single outlet, used for a 240V-only, 20A circuit.  You'll need to take it back and get the correct outlet, a NEMA 5-20 single, instead.

[image]

Comment: Useful graphic,!